# Reading and writing in the same text file using a for loop

Tags: c++

Is it possible to both read and write in a text file using one **for** loop? I want to print out the symbol `.` at zero pos and after every 8 chars in the text. Here's my code, but it doesn't work:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    fstream file("MNMN.txt", ios::out | ios::in );
    string content;
    int i;
    while(file >> content)
    {
        for (size_t i = 0; i < content.size(); i+=8)
        {
            file<<".";
            break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

dDta in my text file is:

```
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP
```

I want it to become:

```
.ABCDEFGH.IJKLMNOP.
```

Answer (score 4):

You cannot do it like that - the data in the file does not "shift" when you write a character, it gets written over.

A common approach for solving this would be as follows:

- Open a temporary file for writing. Write a dot into it
- Open the source file for reading. Read it eight characters at a time
- Every time you read eight characters from the source file, write them to temp file; append a dot
- Once the reading is complete, close both files; move the temporary file in place of the original.